# Does the page visibility API actually support OS screen lock?

Tags: javascript, html

According to [W3 Page Visibility specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/?csw=1#sec-document-interface) and [Mozilla's Page Visibility API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API), the Page Visibility API supports detecting if a browser window is hidden because of the OS lock screen.  Unfortunately, all of the examples I have found seem to indicate that this is not supported.  I cannot get any example JS code or any of my JS code to report that the browser was hidden when I lock my screen (on Windows or OS X).
Some of the examples I have tried:

- http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Performance/PageVisibility/Default.html
- https://jsfiddle.net/wvupJ/
- https://jsfiddle.net/fakj0puw/1/

None of these report that the page was hidden when I lock my OS.  Is this just not supported even though the documentation indicates otherwise?

Because I have to insert some code to be able to link to JSFiddle...

```
var results = document.getElementById('results');

function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document.webkitHidden) {
    results.innerHTML = results.innerHTML + 'Hidden.<br>';
  } else {
    results.innerHTML = results.innerHTML + 'Visible.<br>';
  }
}

document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works on OSX with Safari 8. (For lock and screen saver)

However no browser I found works for Windows.

As of 27/04/2015